# Getting ETIMEDOUT error when running protractor conf.js

Tags: selenium-webdriver, protractor, webdriver-manager

I am a beginner in protractor. I did the installations necessary for running protractor. When tried running the sample script mentioned in the protractor documentation, i am getting ETIMEDOUT error. and the url points to 127.0.0.1:4444. The same url is not accessible manually also. But when trying http://localhost:4444/wd/hub, page opens properly. I am not sure why the conf.js trying to access the 127.0.0.1:4444, even if i give the 'seleniumAddress' parameter to 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub'. Please help me guys to resolve this issue

```js
exports.config = {
  seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
  specs: ['todo-spec.js']
};
```

```js
describe('angularjs homepage todo list', function() {
  it('should add a todo', function() {
    browser.get('https://angularjs.org');

    element(by.model('todoList.todoText')).sendKeys('write first protractor test');
    element(by.css('[value="add"]')).click();

    var todoList = element.all(by.repeater('todo in todoList.todos'));
    expect(todoList.count()).toEqual(3);
    expect(todoList.get(2).getText()).toEqual('write first protractor test');

    // You wrote your first test, cross it off the list
    todoList.get(2).element(by.css('input')).click();
    var completedAmount = element.all(by.css('.done-true'));
    expect(completedAmount.count()).toEqual(2);
  });
});
```

Comment: localhost is nothing but it denotes the  ip address `127.0.0.1`.before executing the protractor test, enter the following command `sudo webdriver-manager update && webdriver-manager start` in a new terminal window and then execute `protractor conf.js`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with the other responses. http://localhost:4444/wd/hub is the same as http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub. Usually this is defined in your `/etc/hosts` file.

Since I imagine you are just trying to run your Protractor tests, as long as you've downloaded the binaries with `webdriver-manager update`, you could do one of the two options:

1. Set `directConnect: true` (and remove `seleniumAddress`. This is available for chrome or firefox (version 47*) without the selenium standalone server.
2. Remove `seleniumAddress` all together. Protractor will launch the selenium standalone server for you before the test and then tear it down when the test is over.

Note: for the above to work, `webdriver-manager update` should run from the project directory to download the binaries to the correct directory. Something like `node node_modules/.bin/webdriver-manager update` or `./node_modules/.bin/webdriver-manager update` should download the driver binaries to `node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium`.

- So why Firefox 47, currently newer versions are not supported. We are currently testing Firefox 48+ but there are still a few outstanding issues.

Comment: Thanks for this, it worked just fine when executed from the selenium directory.

Answer (score 1):

You need 2 terminal for this.

1. In first terminal, run below command:
   **webdriver-manager start**
   this will create a server for node/client to access(that you have added in seleniumAddress)
2. In second terminal, run below command:
   **protractor conf.js**
   This will start your script, by using server created at http://localhost:4444/wd/hub.

And localhost is same as 127.0.0.1.

Answer (score 0):

If localhost is not the same as 127.0.0.1 it sounds like your hosts files has been played around with or some more nefarious networking issue. I do not feel we have enough information to correctly debug why you are having this issue but I would like to suggest a workaround. Why not use your actual local internal IPv4 address?

To get a list of your IPv4 addresses in Windows type

```
ipconfig | findstr /R /C:"IPv4 Address"
```

To get a list of your IPv4 addresses in Linux type

```
hostname -i
```

To get your IPv4 address on a Mac type

```
ifconfig |grep inet
```

The address on mac should be located on the last line between inet and netmask

Your config file should look something like this after

```
exports.config = {
  seleniumAddress: 'http://192.138.0.100:4444/wd/hub',
  specs: ['todo-spec.js']
};
```